# To select the wp-option table from the database

Tags: sql, wordpress

I have to select the table from wordpress database. How can i select the wp-option database table from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
global $wpdb; 
$wpdb->query( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->$options" );
```

But your question is very vague. What is it that you want to achieve?

If its just getting a value for an option, you have another API to do so.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option

e.g. echo get_option('option_name', 'default_value');